# Can you change which .ini file MAMP loads?

Tags: php, mamp

In phpInfo, MAMP's Loaded Configuration File is different to the one output when running `php --ini`:

```
Loaded Configuration File:  /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

Even though, directly above it states the same .ini file as output in the command line:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf
```

Is there a way to get MAMP to load the configuration file listed in the row `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` which is also output with `php --ini`? Or do I just have to edit the one that MAMP is using?

`which php` outputs that it is using MAMP's php system:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One php.ini for CLI (command line) and one for web server.

Keep them separated.

If you want to change the way php behave do it depending of the context.

For cli, change the php.ini you find doing **php --ini** -> Loaded Configuration File

For web server change the file found when doing a phpinfo() from your browser.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it best to keep them separate?

Comment: cli and server are not made for the same purpose, that's why you need separe configuration files? eg: disabling dangerous function server side or error reporting thing and so on.